# Spread windows not working on minimized applications

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window

When I'm using "SUPER" + "W" to spread all running windows I only see the applications that are not minimized and the others are just nothing as seen on picture below.
I have 5 applications running and 3 of them are minimized and this is how it looks:

[image]

How to fix this? I don't know if this is a bug or if this is normal, but i don't like it this way

**UPDATE:**

Just found out that it actually only happens when i use "Super" + "D" to minimize all windows, and then when opening some of them up again it will happen

Comment: not so in ubuntu 12.04 (where ctrl-super-d is used)

Comment: I changed it from ctrl-super-d to super-d, and i have 13.10

Comment: I too would like to know of a solution to this. This problem persists in 13.10 and the current Trusty build.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing this issue. At this time I don't have a solution other than to suggest you to press super-d again to unminimize the windows and then press super-w for window spread.

This is actually a bug in compiz package/unity.
Here are the 3 bug reports I'm following and hoping to get resolved soon.

Bugs [1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1104236)
[2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1154909)
[3](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1104632)